# Delete a specific user from Firebase with laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to delete  a #specific user with key  from firebase with laravel how can i do this !!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOz7w.png)

Comment: Hi Kamar, you need to share a little more context about your problem, what have u done so far to accomplish this but failed? are u using the php sdk? share some piece of sharable code so we can help you better.

Comment: i Connect Android App With Laravel API and i want to use the button delete in laravel to delete users from database "firebase"  and i need  help to do this !!!!i mean "codesource "